# Deploy Azure WebApp from Visual Studio Team Services (VSO)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-management-portal

I try to setup my deployment source in azure portal for a given web app.

When i navigate to *Web App* > *Deployment Source* > *Choose Source* > *Visual Studio Team Services* i am not able to choose my Visual Studio Team Services account.

[image]

after selecting *Visual Studio Team Services* a cannot choose any project. Believe me, there are projects...

[image]

Comment: Does the account that you are using for Azure have permission to your VSTS accounts?

Comment: Yes i think so. I use the same account

Comment: Can you go to http://portal.azure.com and see  your team projects listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that you need to make sure of for this to work:

1. your VSTS account needs to be backed by AAD
2. you need to link it in the Azure portal

For more detail on exactly what this means, see [this wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Setting-up-a-VSTS-account-so-it-can-deploy-to-a-Web-App).

Comment: perfect! Account was not linked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A little update I managed to add connection using only the live login.